# Prove hypergeometric distribution given Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

i'm trying to prove b) here: 
[image: Q&A]

The answers are proveded, so from a) X+Y distributes Binomial B(40,p) 
I'm stuck at proving b).

As I understand, I have to prove that P(X=k) =  $ {25 \choose k} * {15 \choose 10-k}\div {40 \choose 10}$ - mark as *.

Now i'm not sure why, but when I'm looking at $P(X=k)*P(Y=10-k) \div P(X+Y=10)$
i'm getting the correct expression - *. 
But I can't explain the logic behind it. 
Is my intuition correct? How can I prove it?

Comment: Still stuck if someone has a clue

Answer (score 1):

Start by using Bayes' theorem on $\mathbb{P}(X=k|X+Y=10)$, i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(X=k|X+Y=10) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=10|X=k)\mathbb{P}(X=k)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=10)} \; .$$

Now $\mathbb{P}(X+Y=10|X=k)=\mathbb{P}(Y=10-k|X=k)=\mathbb{P}(Y=10-k)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Thus,

$$\mathbb{P}(X=k|X+Y=10) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=10-k)\mathbb{P}(X=k)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=10)} \; .$$

Now, it's just a matter of filling in the distributions for $X$ and $Y$, which you know are binomial.

Comment: If X and Y are independent so I understand, 
BUT who said they are independent ? Why can I assume it ?

Comment: Why would coin tosses be dependent? Maybe they are, but I think the more reasonable assumption is that they aren't. Unless there is some extra information about what Dan and Ron do with the coin, I don't see any reason to assume otherwise.